# calling from another class php

Tags: php

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
   class class1{ 
      public function fun1
      { 
         function fun2
         { 
             echo 'Hello';
         } 
      } 
   } 
   class class2{ 
      //calling fun2 
   } 
?>
```

Can I call function **fun2** in **class2** and how.

Comment: No, you can't call `fun2` from anywhere other than `fun1`, because `fun2` is only visible within `fun1`. That being said, this is a poor design, and you should refactor it so `fun2` is not nested with `fun1`.

Comment: Why would need to nest a function to begin with?

Comment: Nesting a function could be practical if it will only be called inside of another function and it is used repeatively, but with that being said, there are few instances where this is feasible and like others have said, it will most likely result in a poor design. Again, as others have said, when you define anything (functions, variables, etc.) inside of another code block (functions, loops, classes, etc.) they are only available to that code block unless retrieved with special methods.

Comment: @nickb: that's not how PHP works.  Once you call `$class1->fun1()`, `fun2` then becomes visible _globally_.  But not before then.

Comment: @danL: "they are only available to that code block"  Can you specify what PHP version you are talking about?  Once you run a function that itself declares a function within it (as in OP's example), the nested function will then be available globally at least in PHP5.3 and PHP5.4

Comment: For reference on this exact behavior and how it is in fact possible, see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: @nickb It is not javascript

Comment: @PeeHaa and all - I suppose I should've been more specific - It's not possible to call **only** `fun2` from anywhere other than `fun1` (apparently until you call `fun1`), which is how I interpreted the question. Apparently you can call `fun2` after you call `func1`, which just emphasizes my point that this is a bad, perhaps even terrible design.

Comment: @nickb Ah I strongly agree on that. People who do that kind of stuff should be shot without asking questions :D

Comment: I'm too tired to even try to take this serious sorry @bob-the-destroyer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, provided the order is maintained correctly.

```
class test1
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        function doSomethingElse()
        {
            echo "doSomethingElse called\n";
        }
    }
}

class test2
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        doSomethingElse();
    }
}

$t1 = new test1();
$t1->doSomething();

$t2 = new test2();
$t2->doSomething(); // "doSomethingElse called\n";
doSomethingElse(); // "doSomethingElse called\n";
```

By calling `$t1->doSomething();`, the nested `doSomethingElse()` function is loaded.  If you didn't call `$t1->doSomething();` first, then you would receive an error if trying to call the nested function as it doesn't exist yet.

// simplified answer, [see the manual for more details on how/why this is possible](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).

Comment: Also worth noting that you should never ever do this ever. And that if you run `test1::doSomething` multiple times you get an error about trying to redeclare the function.